# `npm install` Output On Jenkins

Tags: node.js, jenkins, npm

Not a huge issue, but I've noticed that `npm install` output on Jenkins comes out a bit weird.

Originally it was an issue with having colors set:

```
 ** [out :: 96.126.118.103] [37m
 ** [out :: 96.126.118.103] [40m
 ** [out :: 96.126.118.103] npm
 ** [out :: 96.126.118.103] [0m
 ** [out :: 96.126.118.103] 
 ** [out :: 96.126.118.103] [0m
 ** [out :: 96.126.118.103] [32m
 ** [out :: 96.126.118.103] [40m
 ** [out :: 96.126.118.103] http
 ** [out :: 96.126.118.103] [0m
 ** [out :: 96.126.118.103] 
 ** [out :: 96.126.118.103] [0m
 ** [out :: 96.126.118.103] [35m
 ** [out :: 96.126.118.103] GET
 ** [out :: 96.126.118.103] [0m
 ** [out :: 96.126.118.103] https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
 ** [out :: 96.126.118.103] [0m
 ** [out :: 96.126.118.103] [37m
 ** [out :: 96.126.118.103] [40m
 ** [out :: 96.126.118.103] npm
 ** [out :: 96.126.118.103] [0m
 ** [out :: 96.126.118.103] 
 ** [out :: 96.126.118.103] [0m
 ** [out :: 96.126.118.103] [32m
 ** [out :: 96.126.118.103] [40m
 ** [out :: 96.126.118.103] http
 ** [out :: 96.126.118.103] [0m
 ** [out :: 96.126.118.103] 
 ** [out :: 96.126.118.103] [0m
 ** [out :: 96.126.118.103] [35m
 ** [out :: 96.126.118.103] GET
 ** [out :: 96.126.118.103] [0m
 ** [out :: 96.126.118.103] https://registry.npmjs.org/mongoose
```

After removing the colors it cleaned up the output pretty well (`npm config set color false`).  Unfortunately it is still adding a line break between names:

```
 ** [out :: 96.126.118.103] npm
 ** [out :: 96.126.118.103] 
 ** [out :: 96.126.118.103] http
 ** [out :: 96.126.118.103] 
 ** [out :: 96.126.118.103] GET
 ** [out :: 96.126.118.103] https://registry.npmjs.org/stylish
 ** [out :: 96.126.118.103] npm
 ** [out :: 96.126.118.103] 
 ** [out :: 96.126.118.103] http
 ** [out :: 96.126.118.103] GET https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
```

Is there any way of forcing these lines to be how they usually display?  Similar to how it's normally displayed in the console:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mongoose
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jade
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
```

It isn't a huge deal, but it does make troubleshooting `npm install`s a bit harder than it should be when issues arise.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

Install the [AnsiColor plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/AnsiColor+Plugin), that should solve it.